Monitor memory modification between instructions in GDB
Is there any way I can check the memory change before and after si, s or something similar commands?
First came out with the idea of dump memory for diff, but haven't dig in how to do it.
Or maybe there is a better way to do this?

I sometimes set up a display statement to print an expression after every single-step.  GDB print statements can have an array operand and various formatting options, so you can get it to print e.g. 20 bytes as hex starting at some address.


Is there any way I can check the memory change before and after si, s or something similar commands?

If you have a small set of memory locations you want to observe, use watchpoints.
